# Writing To A File On A Remote Server

Tags: c#, vb.net

I added a file to \Windev1\wwwroot\dvg

Which is the location on the network of where the source code is that I am using.

Now when I try to open the file in code I get an exception that says

```
Access to the path '\\Windev1\wwwroot\dvg\ProductsToXml.xml' is denied.
```

The code I am using to access the file is

```
Dim writer As New XmlTextWriter("\\Windev1\wwwroot\dvg\ProductsToXml.xml", Nothing)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this from an regular desktop application or from an ASP.NET page?  If it is from an ASP.NET web app then you will need to run your application as a user that has access to the remote folder or impersonate that user before you try to access the file.

If it is a regular desktop application then I would expect that you would get the same error in Windows explorer which just means that you need to give your logged in user permissions on the remote folder.

Also, if your app is a Windows service you should change the user credentials that the service runs under to a user that has access to the network share.

Comment: I tried adding my name to the folder with the code in it. I set my name to Full Control permissions. As well unchecked the ReadOnly checkbox on the folder. But it didnt work, do I have to do this somewhere else?

Comment: what kind of application is it? windows form, console, service, web app?

Comment: Judging on the answer vote-up I'm assuming you found how to set impersonation for your web app in IIS.  If you need any more pointers let me know.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is described in the error; the user account that the OS is using to run your application does not have sufficient rights as a non-elevated user to access the file.

Just a guess, but usually access to web server directories is pretty tightly controlled at the OS level. Make sure that your user account (or NetworkService if this code is a Windows service or web app) has read/modify permissions on this file. Simply having the user be an Administrator won't work; Administrator accounts are run by default with standard user permissions, and are "elevated" to administrative privileges when necessary (which a program will not request by default; it will simply fail).